# Mysql tree structure get count of childs with level using recursive query

Tags: mysql, tree, database-administration, hierarchical-data

I am using **WITH RECURSIVE** using **UNION ALL** mysql query to get level of each node and it is working fine. Now I just want to get count of childs for each node.

```
WITH RECURSIVE generation AS 

(SELECT id, name, parent_id, 0 AS generation_number FROM users WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
child.name, 
child.parent_id
generation_number+1 AS generation_number 
FROM users child 
JOIN generation g ON g.id = child.parent_id ) 

SELECT id, name, parent_id, generation_number FROM generation;
```

Above MySql query returning below table as result excepting last column i.e. "Count of child". What need to do in same query to get count of (Union All) childs.

| id | name | parent_id | generation/level | Count of child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | C | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | D | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | E | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | F | 4 | 3 | 0 |

Here is source data for creating table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sponsor_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive','Deleted') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `sponsor_id`, `parent_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `password`, `image`, `status`, `amount`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'a', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:42:09', '2022-10-12 04:42:09'),
(2, NULL, 1, NULL, 'b', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:43:34', '2022-10-12 04:43:34'),
(3, NULL, 1, NULL, 'c', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:43:34', '2022-10-12 04:43:34'),
(4, NULL, 1, NULL, 'e', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(5, NULL, 2, NULL, 'f', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(6, NULL, 2, NULL, 'g', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(7, NULL, 2, NULL, 'h', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(8, NULL, 3, NULL, 'i', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(9, NULL, 3, NULL, 'j', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(10, NULL, 3, NULL, 'k', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-10-12 04:47:31'),
(11, NULL, 4, NULL, 'l', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(12, NULL, 4, NULL, 'm', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(13, NULL, 4, NULL, 'n', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(14, NULL, 5, NULL, 'o', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(15, NULL, 5, NULL, 'p', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(16, NULL, 6, NULL, 'q', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(17, NULL, 6, NULL, 'r', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(18, NULL, 7, NULL, 's', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(19, NULL, 8, NULL, 't', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(20, NULL, 8, NULL, 'u', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(21, NULL, 8, NULL, 'v', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(22, NULL, 9, NULL, 'w', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(23, NULL, 9, NULL, 'x', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(24, NULL, 10, NULL, 'y', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23'),
(25, NULL, 10, NULL, 'z', '', '', '', NULL, 'Active', '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-10-12 04:50:23');
```

Comment: Provide source data as a fiddle or as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina- I added sample data

Comment: Do you need in immediate childs amount? or in total amount of childs, including childs of childs and up to the end of the tree?

Comment: @Akina - only immediate childs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use COUNT and JOIN.

```sql
SELECT g1.id, g1.name, g1.parent_id, g1.generation_number,COALESCE(g2.CountOfChild,0)
  FROM generation g1 LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT parent_id,COUNT(*) CountOfChild FROM generation GROUP BY parent_id) g2
    ON g1.id=g2.parent_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's working fine. Somehow can we manage this within Union All in place of doing one more join?

Comment: I think it is necessary to use COUNT and JOIN even in CTE.

Comment: Can you please help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333566/mysql-mariadb-stored-procedure-set-one-variable-value-from-selected-row-through