# Mysql/mariadb stored procedure set one variable value from selected row through join operation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb-10.4

I have one MySql stored procedure i.e. selecting one row using left join. How can I set one value into OUT parameter from result set.

> Database table which one I am using as:

```
INSERT INTO `user_pool` (`id`, `pool_id`, `user_id`, `parent_id`, `sponsor_id`, `amount`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, NULL, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:42:09', '2022-11-02 04:44:27'),
(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:43:34', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(3, 1, 3, 1, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:43:34', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(4, 2, 4, 3, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 05:32:03'),
(5, 1, 5, 2, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(6, 1, 6, 2, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(7, 2, 7, 2, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(8, 1, 8, 3, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(9, 1, 9, 3, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(10, 2, 10, 4, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:47:31', '2022-11-02 07:21:34'),
(11, 2, 11, 2, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 12:30:03'),
(12, 2, 12, 8, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 12:30:43'),
(13, 2, 13, 4, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(14, 1, 14, 5, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(15, 1, 15, 5, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(16, 1, 16, 6, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(17, 1, 17, 6, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(18, 2, 18, 7, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(19, 1, 19, 8, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(20, 1, 20, 8, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(21, 2, 21, 8, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(22, 1, 22, 9, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(23, 1, 23, 9, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(24, 2, 24, 10, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 12:23:34'),
(25, 2, 25, 10, 1, '0.00', '2022-10-12 04:50:23', '2022-11-02 12:23:40'),
(26, 2, 1, NULL, 1, '0.00', '2022-11-01 12:12:56', '2022-11-02 04:43:16'),
(27, 2, 2, 1, 1, '0.00', '2022-11-02 05:18:40', '2022-11-02 05:18:40'),
(28, 2, 3, 1, 1, '0.00', '2022-11-02 05:19:54', '2022-11-02 05:19:54'),
(29, 2, 8, 3, 1, '0.00', '2022-11-02 05:21:39', '2022-11-02 07:05:53');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `user_pool`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_pool`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_pool_parent` (`user_id`,`pool_id`) USING BTREE;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user_pool`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_pool`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
COMMIT;
```

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_sp`(IN `xid` INT, IN `xpool_id` INT, IN `xtree` INT, OUT `xnode` INT)
BEGIN
      
      WITH RECURSIVE generation AS 
      ( SELECT parent_id, user_id FROM user_pool WHERE user_id=xid AND pool_id=xpool_id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
      child.parent_id, 
      child.user_id
      FROM user_pool child 
      JOIN generation g ON g.user_id = child.parent_id WHERE child.pool_id=xpool_id) 
      
    (SELECT g1.user_id, g1.parent_id, COALESCE(g2.CountOfChild,0) as CountOfChild
FROM generation g1 LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT parent_id,COUNT(*) CountOfChild FROM generation GROUP BY parent_id) g2
  ON g1.user_id=g2.parent_id HAVING CountOfChild < xtree ORDER BY user_id, CountOfChild LIMIT 1);
 

  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Above stored procedure result is

| user_id | parent_id | CountOfChild |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |

I want to select/return user_id in OUT variable i.e. xnode. Something like SET user_id INTO xnode from but it's not working.

> Note: I am using Version 10.4.24-MariaDB - mariadb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember how many columns you are going to select with SELECT statement. Count of return variables must be equal to selected columns.

> To assign value into variables use INTO statement at the end of SELECT statement like below code:

```
    (SELECT g1.user_id, g1.parent_id, COALESCE(g2.CountOfChild,0) as CountOfChild
FROM generation g1 LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT parent_id,COUNT(*) CountOfChild FROM generation GROUP BY parent_id) g2
  ON g1.user_id=g2.parent_id HAVING CountOfChild < xtree ORDER BY user_id, CountOfChild LIMIT 1) INTO xnode, @var2, @var3;
```